# What does "Property where class => someFunction" mean in C#

Tags: c#

I'm browsing through the [EF7 code on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbContext.cs#L826) and found a line that looks like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class => _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
```

I have seen that syntax before on a class level, like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : class
```

Which says that `T` should be of type class. But the line from the EF7 source confuses me. I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [expression-bodied member](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members), a new syntax in C# 6.

It's a method, not a property. C# doesn't allow generic properties.

It's the same as

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
}
```

Comment: It's not a field or method. It defines a get only property

Comment: @dotctor It's a method, not property. Notice the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is a bit confusing indeed, but actually the lambda construct here has nothing to do with generic constraints. It's just an **Expression-Bodied Method** that happened to have a generic constraint.

You can think of it as:

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
}
```

See [Roslyn Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-method-like-members)

Answer (score 1):

It's a C# 6.0 feature called Expression Bodied Method.

Read [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html) about it.

The code is equivalent to:

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class 
{
    return _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
}
```

Comment: your code will not compile as the function does not return anything